# Entity Framework How to reference a row instead of create new row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unique-constraint, unique-key

I have 2 tables ***Gender*** and ***ApplicationUser***.
I want each user in ApplicationUser reference a gender in Gender table.
but now after creating each applicationUser instance a new gender is created in Gender table. Please note that I recently made the Gender Name to Unique and it throws an exception.

Here is my code

```
public sealed class Uow : IUow, IDisposable {

    public Uow(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider) {
        CreateDbContext();
        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;

    }

    public IApplicationUserRepository ApplicationUsers => GetRepo<IApplicationUserRepository>();
    public IFileExtensionRepository FileExtensions => GetRepo<IFileExtensionRepository>();
    public IFileRecordRepository FileRecords => GetRepo<IFileRecordRepository>();
    public IFileTypeRepository FileTypes => GetRepo<IFileTypeRepository>();
    public IGenderRepository Genders => GetRepo<IGenderRepository>();
    public IMembershipClassRepository MembershipClass => GetRepo<IMembershipClassRepository>();

    public async Task<int> CommitAsync() {
        return await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void DiscardChanges() {
        var changedEntries = DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var entry in changedEntries) {
            switch (entry.State) {
                case EntityState.Modified:
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified; //Revert changes made to deleted entity.
                    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Detached:
                    break;
                case EntityState.Unchanged:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    private T GetRepo<T>() where T : class {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
    }

    private void CreateDbContext() {
        DbContext = new DatabaseContext();
        DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    private DatabaseContext DbContext {
        get; set;
    }

    private IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class GenderRepository : EfRepository<Gender>, IGenderRepository {
    public GenderRepository(DatabaseContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) { }

    public async Task<Gender> GetByNameAsync(string genderName) {
        return await DbContext.Gender.SingleAsync(x => x.Name == genderName);
    }
}

public class Gender {
    public const string Male = "Male";
    public const string Female = "Female";
    public const string NotSpecified = "NotSpecified";

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(12), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    [MinLength(3), MaxLength(16)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128), MinLength(2), DefaultValue(null)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128), MinLength(2), DefaultValue(null)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender{ get; set; }
}

async Task Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
    // doing some stuff
    user = new ApplicationUser {
        Email = model.Email,
        DisplayName = model.DisplayName,
        Gender = await Uow.Genders.GetByNameAsync(Gender.NotSpecified),
        MembershipClass = await Uow.MembershipClass.GetByNameAsync(MembershipClass.Normal),
    };

    user.ProfilePicture = new FileRecord();

    user.ProfilePicture.Name = "Profile";
    user.ProfilePicture.FileType = await Uow.FileTypes.GetByNameAsync(FileType.ProfileImage);
    user.ProfilePicture.Extension = await Uow.FileExtensions.GetByNameAsync(FileExtension.JPG);
    user.ProfilePicture.Size = 18932;

    // doing some stuff
    await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    await Uow.CommitAsync();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an Enum rather than a class for Gender? It will then store the enum value against the ApplicationUser. You could then use something like https://github.com/timabell/ef-enum-to-lookup if you want the enums mapped in the DB

Comment: Not yet. I'm viewing your link and see how can I use it.
Thank You.

Comment: You dont *need* that nuget package, you'd still get a zero and one for male and female in the DB for example. That package is nice though as it creates lookup tables that you can join on to get the string values to make it more readable...

Comment: It is advised to add a GenderId to your User class. But in this case, an enum is enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yeah you're right but it is not the only place I'm trying to use this method. I have many other places to reference and they are more than one simple property. any way... thanx

Comment: If you want this resolved then add the GetByNameAsync and the code path that calls Context.SaveChanges() as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Check the update

Comment: Well, a lot of unnecessary code (interfaces) and I still can't see the Add() being called or what CommitAsync does. Write a [mcve] .

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well I tried to minify the code.CommentAsync is calling inside of Gender Repository and I added the Uow Core (and a little more) code. also removed Interfaces from here

Comment: The point is that `UserManager` doesn't have the same context as your `Uow`.

Comment: @GertArnold You mean internally in the framework or I have done some thing wrong.

Comment: I test the exact situation in new project inside a new solution where there is no UserManager and ApplicationUser there and it was perfectly fine.
It is so annoying.

Comment: I've found the solution and I'll post it soon. :) Thank You every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to ***@GertArnold*** 's comment.

After almost 2 weeks I found the solution which is some where in the middle way of program flow I was creating a new Instance of ***DatabaseContext*** and this was the problem.
By practice I found that in this approach you must have single Instance of ***DatabaseContext*** , and secondly in my situation which I was creating a new *ApplicationUser* and I wanted to assign *Gender* reference to newly created user and it was wrong because I had no reference to the ***UserManager*** ***DatabaseContext*** so the system was trying to create new instance of gender which it was ***Unique*** property and cause and exception.So I created the ***ApplicationUser*** and then get it in the same context which I wanted to assign ***Gender***.

Answer (score 1):

At this case you simply should assign `Gender` property to reference on existing `Gender` instead of created one by means of `new` keyword:

```
var maleGender = context.Genders.Single(x => x.Name == Gender.Male);
var newUser = new ApplicationUser 
{ 
    Gender = maleGender
    //wrong approach:
    //Gender = new Gender { Name = Gender.Male }
};
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you. I already have tried this with FirstOrDefault extension method but didn't work.
I am not creating a new instance and I've tracked the program flow to see if in some other place it is instantiating (may be implicitly) and I found none.
It is so confusing.